# Completely change the response of spring project from rendering jsp to json object

Tags: java, json, spring

I have developed a spring application and now I required to develop an android application with the same functionality. Now what i want is to use the same web controller part for sending json object in response with those url mappings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@james i think you could use **ContentNegotiationViewResolver** for the type of requirement you have. The proper implementation you can get from [this link](http://www.mkyong.com/spring-mvc/spring-3-mvc-contentnegotiatingviewresolver-example/)